# refer directly to a block element in a html page

Tags: css

here is the code

```
<div id = "content">
  <div id = "text">
    <h1>Text</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm a newbie and I would know if it is possible, using css, that I can apply a style only to that `h1` element inside those div without any other h1 out of those div could be feel the style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
div#content > div#text > h1 { some style here }
```

In this case you will touch only `h1` which is placed in hierarchy like you described.

Comment: what is the meaning of > symbol?

Comment: It means that next element will follow exactly after current one on the next level of hierarchy. If you are using it without `>` it means that next element can be on any deeper level of hierarchy inside of the current.

Comment: There's no need to include the tag names, as each `id` can only be used once. On that same note, `#content >` can be removed entirely (assuming that's the only way each is output) since there *should* only be *one* `#content` and `#text` in each document.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here is an example.

```
div#content div#text h1 {/* your style */}
```

This will allow you to only add css to these items in this specific order.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to include `div` before `#content` or `#text`, as each `id` can only be used once. If you change to using `class` instead, you may want to include `div` before it (e.g. `div.content`) in case other tags also use that `class`.

## Match exact structure

```
#text > h1 {/* Styles */}
```

***although you should use this, if you use `class` instead:***

```
div.content > div.text > h1 {/* Styles */}
```

*This will match:*

- `<div id="content"><div id="text"><h1>`

*But not:*

- `<div id="content"><div id="text"><div><h1>`
- `<div id="content"><div><div id="text"><h1>`

## Match any structure

```
#text h1 {/* Styles */}
```

***although you should use this, if you use `class` instead:***

```
div.content div.text h1 {/* Styles */}
```

*This will match:*

- `<div id="content"><div id="text"><h1>`
- `<div id="content"><div id="text"><div><h1>`
- `<div id="content"><div><div id="text"><h1>`